# How to get multiple elements with same name in a node with XDocument?

Tags: c#, xml, xml-parsing, linq-to-xml

I have a xml with this strucure:

```
   <news>
      <id><![CDATA[1]]></id>
      <title><![CDATA[My title]]></title>
      <date><![CDATA[17-06-2013]]></date>
      <machine><![CDATA[a]]></machine>
      <machine><![CDATA[b]]></machine>
      <machine><![CDATA[c]]></machine>
      <machine><![CDATA[d]]></machine>
   </news>
   <news>
      <id><![CDATA[2]]></id>
      <title><![CDATA[My title 2]]></title>
      <date><![CDATA[17-06-2013]]></date>
      <machine><![CDATA[a]]></machine>
      <machine><![CDATA[b]]></machine>
      <machine><![CDATA[c]]></machine>
      <machine><![CDATA[d]]></machine>
   </news>
```

and I read it like this:

```
var datas = from query in loadedData.Descendants("news")
                            select new News
                            {
                                Title = (string)query.Element("title"),
                                Id = (string)query.Element("id"),
                                StrDate = (string)query.Element("date"),
                                list = query.Elements("machine")
                            };
```

the code

```
list = query.Elements("machine")
```

doesn't work. How to get a list with the elements with tags "machine"

Comment: try using Descendants instead of Elements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below mentioned code should work out. I have considered list as an object of List

```
var datas = from query in loadedData.Descendants("news")
                                select new News
                                {
                                    Title = (string)query.Element("title"),
                                    Id = (string)query.Element("id"),
                                    StrDate = (string)query.Element("date"),
                                    list = (from xele in query.Descendants("machine")
                                           select xele.Value).ToList<string>();   
                                };
```